# Cambiar estado si fecha es igual o mayor a el dia de hoy

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Tengo este código:

```
$activox_count_query = tep_db_query("select * 
  from " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o, " . TABLE_GANTS . " g 
  where o.orders_status = '32' 
    and g.orders_id = o.orders_id 
    and g.title = 'Activar Servicio' 
    and g.start >= now()");
$activox_count = tep_db_fetch_array($activox_count_query);

tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_ORDERS . " 
  set orders_status = '32',
    last_modified = now()
  where orders_id = '" . (int)$activox_count['orders_id'] . "' 
    and orders_status = '31'");
```

Necesito si la fecha de la tabla gants que contenga el `title = 'Activar Servicio'` y el start igual o mayor a la fecha de hoy, realice un update a la tabla orders.

Que pase del estado 31 al 32 si y solo si el dia es mayor o igual al de hoy, en formato `YYYY:MM:DD` incluyen las `HH:MM:SS`

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar las estructura de las tablas `orders y gants`?. De esa forma podríamos saber cual es el tipo de valor esperado para cada columna.

Comment: vale muy agradecido, tengo ahora otra duda no se con que comando puedo hacer lo siguiente, cuando se ejecute el update despues de hacerlo como realizo un reload la pagina index.php la cual yo no la tengo abierta, esta pertenece al cliente, y si la tiene abierta necesito que se ejecute un reload para que cargue el nuevo estado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías actualizar de **todas las ordenes** con un solo `query`.

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
tep_db_query("
  UPDATE ".TABLE_ORDERS."
  SET orders_status = '32',
    last_modified = NOW()
  WHERE orders_status = '31'
    AND orders_id IN (
      SELECT orders_id 
      FROM ".TABLE_GANTS." 
      WHERE start >= NOW()
        AND title = 'Activar Servicio'
    )
");
```